# How can I get the whole sub path with JAX-RS?

Tags: jax-rs

With following URL.

```
http://doma.in/context/resource/some/.../undefined
```

I want to get the path name after `../resource` which is `/some/.../undefined`

```java
@Path("/resource")
class Response Resource {
    final String path; // "/some/.../undefined"
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

There is, as answered, a way to do this.

```java
@Path("/resource")
class class Resource {

    @Path("/{paths: .+}")
    public String readPaths() {
        final String paths
            = uriInfo.getPathParameters().getFirst("paths");
    }

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;
}
```

When I invoke

```
http://.../context/resource/paths/a/b/c
```

I get

```
a/b/c
```

.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the URI information from [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html), which you can inject either as a field or method parameter, using the [`@Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation.

```
public Response getResponse(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
}

-- OR --

@Context 
private UriInfo uriInfo;
```

- You can get the absolute request path with [`UriInfo.getAbsoultePath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29)

  ```
  http://doma.in/context/resource/some/somthingelse/undefined
  ```
- You can get the relative path to the base uri from [`UriInfo.getPath()`](http://doma.in/context/resource/some/.../undefined).

  ```
  /resource/some/somthingelse/undefined
  ```
- You can get a list of path segments (each section between slashes is a path segment) with [`UriInfo.getPathSegments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments%28%29). Here is an [example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27246614/2587435).

There's a bunch of methods you can use for reading the URI. Just look at the API linked above.